# How do I validate two sets of checkboxes with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have two sets of check boxes. At least one in each group has to be checked. How do I accomplish this with Jquery? Here is my link to JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TknCq/

Comment: Might need a bit of info around the scenario.. when does the check on whether at least box is selected occur? When you submit the form (i.e. on a button click) or every time one of the boxes is selected/unselected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a:

```
$('ul:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').length == 2
```

where **2** is the number of groups.  It gives you **the number of ul's** that **contain a checked input** *that has to be 2 in this case* ;) So it checks that every `ul` that contains `checkboxes` has at least one `checked`.

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LZLRy/)**

Comment: That work!! Thanks. How do I program the logic if both are unchecked then an error message will display?

Comment: Thanks. Here how I wrote the logic thanks to your help:
$('input').bind('click', function () {
                    if ($('ul:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').length == 2) {
                        $('#searchValidationError').hide();
                    }else{
      $('#searchValidationError').html('<p>Please check a box under Claim Type & Claim Status');
                        $('#searchValidationError').show();
     }
    });

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all the inputs in the wrappers that have an attribute checked and if the length > 0 you have at least one checkbox checked:

```
var checkboxes_claimStatus = $("#field-claimStatus-wrapper").find("input:checked");
if(checkboxes_claimStatus.length)
{
    alert('checked');
}
```

Do the same for the other group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if($("#field-claimType-wrapper input:checked").length > 0){

}

if($("#field-claimStatus-wrapper input:checked").length > 0){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this...

```
$("input[name='claimType']:checked").size() > 0 && $("input[name='claimStatus']:checked").size() > 0
```

checking if the checked checkbox count in both groups is greater than 0

Here is the updated jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TknCq/5/)